# Change app icon every day

Tags: ios, ios7

How to change **app icon** every day like mac calendar app in **iOS**.

I try to use badge but this is not correct

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
```

I have some icon images in application that stored in array and i want to set icon image from that image array programmeticaly. Is this possible in iOS7 ?

Comment: There is no public API for this

Comment: Is it possible or not in iPhone?

Comment: The short explanation for "There is no public API for this" is "No, it is not possible."

Comment: You can change app icon from iOS 10.3 onwards. iOS 10.3 comes with dynamic app changing feature. Developers will now be able to change app icons without an app update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the Icons on your normal Apps on iOS, but you can change them between updates.

You can change the icons of Newsstand Apps (i.e. magazine Apps inside the Newsstand), if you are making such an App.